# Get the substrings from a given string

Tags: c#, string

I have the below string and need to get only the strings Location, `Andrew Jacob` and `VAAS HARI`.

```
p {margin-left: 0px; color: Black  /style> /head> p>LocationA</p> font color=#888888>Organizer: /font> p>Andrew Jacob /p>  fontcolor=#888888> Attendee(s):  /font> p>VAAS HARI /p> `/head>
```

I tried to replace the other strings , remove or trim, but couldn't get. Please help.

Comment: Please add the code you used to replace the other strings. Also, how dynamic is this text?

Comment: The text will be coming in the same format always , Code i tried is pretty static, by replacing each string by "". but that didnt seem a good one.

Comment: You can use regex to replace data between HTML tags

Comment: How about `Substring` method?

Comment: Is this your actual string? If you're skipping `<` characters to keep the html sane, use the `{}`  button in the toolbar and you'll get nicely formatted code that renders better.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad [Don't use Regex with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3043)

Comment: Use the full html and parse the values using Html parser.

Comment: @mybirthname .. I didnt knew there is a HTML parser in C# .. i am from Java .. Will try this and paste back the results. Thankyou for suggesting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data's always on the same line number you could try something like this (you may need to try without `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as that'll remove blank lines)

```
string input=@"
p {margin-left: 0px; color: Black}

LocationA

Organizer:
Andrew Jacob

Attendee(s):
VAAS HARI
";

string[] lines  = input.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var location = lines[1];
var organizer = lines[3];
var attendees = lines[5];
```

Comment: I will try this ..Thankyou for sharing the idea ..will post back the output

Comment: I used a similar way after trying the options. I am able to parse the same now. Thankyou for your idea

Answer (score 0):

```
string search = "Andrew Jacob";
int startIndex = input.IndexOf(search);
if(startIndex >= 0)
{
    string output = input.Substring(startIndex, search.Length);
}
else
{
    // search Not found in input
}
```

Comment: While this might possibly be the correct answer, it doesn't look convincing without commentaries and only code. Please consider adding a commentary for a better chance of being accepted.

Comment: Thankyou ,but the output is dynamic ...so it may not be Andrew Jacob Or LocationA always ...